# VueJs clear form after success

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to clear my inputs in modal after my data saved successfully, I've tried several solution I found here such as `reset()` or `myData = '';` but none of them worked for me.

## Code

`Vue method`

```
submit: function(e) {
    axios.post('/api/saveVerse', this.verse)
    .then(res => {
        this.isLoading = false
        $('#exampleModal').modal('toggle');
        this.getVerses.push( res.data.verse );
    })
    .catch(error => {
        this.errors = error.response.data.errors
        this.isLoading = false
    })
},
```

`Vue Template`

```
<form @submit.prevent="submit" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-md-3 mb-3">
                <label for="validationTooltip01">Verse Number</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltip01" v-model="verse.number" placeholder="Verse Number" required>
                <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                    Verse Number Is Required.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9 mb-3">
                <label for="validationTooltip01">Heading</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="validationTooltip01" v-model="verse.heading" placeholder="Verse Heading">
                <div class="valid-tooltip">
                    Heading Looks Good!
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                <label for="validationTooltip02">Verse</label>
                <textarea name="body" class="form-control" id="validationTooltip02" v-model="verse.body" placeholder="Verse" cols="15" rows="5" required></textarea>
                <div class="invalid-tooltip">
                    Verse Body Is Required.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Any idea?**

## Update

How I get my form data...

```
data() {
    return {
        //...
        verse: {
            number: '',
            heading: '',
            body: '',
            book_id: '',
            chapter_id: '',
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: you can assign empty value to all field of form

Comment: you mean like my sample `myData = '';`?

Comment: yes exactly, but in your code how did you apply that?

Comment: I've tried all 3 ways such as: `this.verse.number = '';` also `this.number = '';` and `this.verse= '';` none worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to  bind the response like below.and verify please

```
submit: function(e) {
axios.post('/api/saveVerse', this.verse)
.then(res => {
    this.isLoading = false
    $('#exampleModal').modal('toggle');
    this.getVerses.push( res.data.verse );
    // resetting your v-model:
    this.verse = {
        number: '',
        heading: '',
        body: ''
    };
}).bind(this)
.catch(error => {
    this.errors = error.response.data.errors
    this.isLoading = false
})
},
```

Comment: it's working however you misplaced the bind code, correct one is this `}).bind(this)`

Comment: oops!! sorry .noted

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
submit: function(e) {
axios.post('/api/saveVerse', this.verse)
.then(res => {
    this.isLoading = false
    $('#exampleModal').modal('toggle');
    this.getVerses.push( res.data.verse );
    // resetting your v-model:
    this.verse = {
        number: '',
        heading: '',
        body: ''
    };
   // Try this also...
   e.preventDefault();
})
.catch(error => {
    this.errors = error.response.data.errors
    this.isLoading = false
})
```

},

Comment: still data exist in my form

Comment: @mafortis can you create some sandbox code and fiddle with your code.

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` didn't work but `bind` did. thank you for trying too help.